# Omit fields from wizard generated MVC views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to avoid having unwanted fields generated into MVC views by the default VS wizard?  It would be nice if a `ScaffoldColumn=false` annotation could achieve this, but it doesn't.

Of course I have a mile long wish-list regarding generated views, e.g. I would prefer EditorFor as a default for all generated fields.  I suppose this is T4 and T$MVC territory only, or are there other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the t4 templates that generate those views.

[T4 Templates: A Quick-Start Guide for ASP.NET MVC Developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx)